# how to find how the most popular post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

1. List item

each day I want to find the "most popular" post on the website and feature it on the home page.

For each post, I'm keeping track of how many times it has been "liked", "disliked", "favorited" and "viewed".

I would like to run a daily cron job where I do something like:

```
  post = Post.order("popularity_score DESC").first
  post.feature!
```

My question is, how should I compute the value of popularity_score?

Is there a formula that takes into consideration "statistical significance"?  Meaning, a post which has 1 "like" vote and nothing else, although having a 100% approval rating, it shouldn't mean much because only one person voted on it.

In general I have these loose ideas off the top of my head:

1. a post with 10 likes and no other votes is more popular than a
   post with 1 like vote.
2. a post post with more "dislikes" than
   "likes" should have a lower score than a post with more "likes" than
   "dislikes"
3. a post with 20 views and no other votes is more
   popular than a post with 3 views.

I've punched in some arbitrary formulas to try to satisfy this goal, but there are exactly that, arbitrary and I don't really know if there is a better way to go about this?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just take the SO approach? it seems rather decent.

- `+` gives 10 points
- `-` substracts 2 points
- `view` add a low number, like 0.01 point
- `comment` add 2 points

Comment: That is interesting.  How do you know that formula?  Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to not reset your counter each day (that leaves the "most popular" open to a single vote).

Instead, weight the votes by their age -- newer votes count more than older votes.  This will give you gradual and meaningful rerankings over time.